# Tracking user activity with Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have to write an extension to track user activity in Chrome, that is, which URLs the user opens by clicking links or by typing. Is this possible to implement? and what is the best way to do this? I tried to register chrome.webRequest listener inside background page:

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    function(details) {
        alert(details.url);
        return {cancel: false};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    []
);
```

but unfortunately this tracks everything that happens inside Chrome , for example, just by typing few characters of an URL, I caught about 30 requests to unrelated sites like Google Plus, Google Images, Google Ads, and lots of pages that have very little relation to the content the user wants to retrieve. What I want is to catch the initial user's URL, but not all the pages , images, CSS and all that stuff related to the initially fetched page.

How should I do this?

Comment: I have similar task. Would you mind sharing your approach?

Comment: @ying - Did you find anything relevant? I have similar task can you please share your findings?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Google Analytics](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics), it helps you use Google Analytics to track the usage of your extension, including page views, events and so on.

Comment: No, I am not trying to track my own extension usage, I am trying to track what users are browsing.

Comment: @Nulik - I have a similar requirement, did you find anything helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Include the script in every page by using * in the manifest, and then use the content script to [send](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) the tab url (window.location or something) to the background page.